# SIMPLE cURL not returning results in working URL

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a URL that returns raw JSON data - my simple cURL code seems to return nothing.  I've looked everywhere. Note that the url DOES return the data, but the cURL does not.

```
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.actha.us/events/upcoming_events?key=ZyXHnacvw8BjXKVel0sPXIxabEA29jId");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);       
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "output = " . $output;
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors? Also, note that it's an `https` url, so it might need something extra (SSL) to work.

Comment: `if ($output === false) { die(curl_error($ch)) }` will probably tell you what's wrong, instead of us playing 20 questions trying to guess what the problem is

Comment: I'm sorry - I had checked for errors, and none were returned. It was simply being returned blank without the https being dealt with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with HTTPS, don't forget to add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

It disables certificate verification.

Comment: THANKS! This returns what I;'m looking for except the error, "The requested resource does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit. "  - Where do I fix THAT?

Comment: Why are you sending post request? You don't have any post data set.

Comment: Remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` line.

Comment: FIXED - my bad was copying code using POST, and forgetting how to deal with HTTPS. Thanks very much